# mongodb setFeatureCompatibilityVersion to 5.0 fails in a sharded cluster with "BSON field 'ShardCollectionType.uuid' is missing but a required field"

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

We have a MongoDB community edition, that we upgraded from 4.4.18 to 5.0.19.
Last step of the upgrade, changing CFV to 5.0 fails, seems to a corruption in metadata:

```
mongos> db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "5.0" } )
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Failed command { _flushRoutingTableCacheUpdatesWithWriteConcern: \"9a79fb83-7c4e-4927-88ec-b462438b8471.galileo.prepared_data\", syncFromConfig: true, writeConcern: { w: \"majority\", wtimeout: 60000 } } for database 'admin' on shard 'SRS_4' :: caused by :: Failed to read persisted collections entry for collection '9a79fb83-7c4e-4927-88ec-b462438b8471.galileo.prepared_data'. :: caused by :: Failed to read the '9a79fb83-7c4e-4927-88ec-b462438b8471.galileo.prepared_data' entry locally from config.collections :: caused by :: BSON field 'ShardCollectionType.uuid' is missing but a required field",
    "code" : 40414,
    "codeName" : "Location40414",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1694101525, 7),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"kAq76gd44IS7c0NMCUBdZSxmJns="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("7225622669759086594")
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1694101518, 3)
}
```

We have 4 shards, and this collection doesn't appear to have any chunks in SRS_4. sh.status() shows:

```
                9a79fb83-7c4e-4927-88ec-b462438b8471.galileo.prepared_data
                        shard key: { "correlationId" : "hashed" }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                SRS_1   2
                                SRS_2   2
                                SRS_3   2
                        { "correlationId" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "correlationId" : NumberLong("-6148914691236517204") } on : SRS_1 Timestamp(5, 0)
                        { "correlationId" : NumberLong("-6148914691236517204") } -->> { "correlationId" : NumberLong("-3074457345618258602") } on : SRS_1 Timestamp(6, 0)
                        { "correlationId" : NumberLong("-3074457345618258602") } -->> { "correlationId" : NumberLong(0) } on : SRS_2 Timestamp(7, 0)
                        { "correlationId" : NumberLong(0) } -->> { "correlationId" : NumberLong("3074457345618258602") } on : SRS_2 Timestamp(8, 0)
                        { "correlationId" : NumberLong("3074457345618258602") } -->> { "correlationId" : NumberLong("6148914691236517204") } on : SRS_3 Timestamp(9, 0)
                        { "correlationId" : NumberLong("6148914691236517204") } -->> { "correlationId" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : SRS_3 Timestamp(10, 0)
```

All replicaset members (all shards and config) now show:

```
    "featureCompatibilityVersion" : {
        "version" : "4.4",
        "targetVersion" : "5.0"
    },
```

Any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks

I tried redoing the setFeatureCompatibilityVersion. I also tried restarting SRS_4 replicaset members.
No change in outcome, still the same error.

Comment: Name `9a79fb83-7c4e-4927-88ec-b462438b8471.galileo.prepared_data` looks rather like a temporary collection. Do you need it? If not, simply try to drop it.

Comment: It's not really temporary. I could mongodump/drop/mongorestore. This is nonprod, but if I run into the same issue when we upgrade prod, dropping it would be a problem. So I was hoping to solve it by possibly correcting the collection it complains about, adding a missing required field (except that I have no idea on how to do that :) ).

Comment: I would assume, this is a temporary collection which was created automatically but not dropped for whatever reason (e.g. shutdown of database). Check your application if this collection is really in use.

Comment: I dropped that collection, and then got the same type of error for another database. I kept dropping collections, already 10 of them, and the error keeps popping up, for another db. I have over 5000 databases. If anyone has an idea how to fix this differently, I'd be happy to try it.

Comment: The error is complaining about the collections not having a UUID.  Collections were first give UUIDs in MongoDB 3.6, so it would be really odd that they didn't already have them in MongoDB 4.4.  You might try restarting everything (including the mongoses), and make sure all of the processes are on the same version

Comment: I just wanted to comment that I have a (live) database with tens of thousands of collections, and upon querying `config.cache.collections` on the primaries for various shards, about 1/3 to 1/2 of them are missing UUIDs! And these collections are neither temporary nor empty.

This cluster has been continuously running since before mongo 3.6 even, so this is likely an issue for old continuously running mongo clusters (i.e. prod clusters).

Still searching for the "proper" fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a final answer, but you can query all temporary collection with this:

```
db.getSiblingDB('config').databases.find({ _id: { $nin: ['admin', 'local', 'config'] } }).forEach(doc => {
   let collections = db.getSiblingDB(doc._id).getCollectionNames();
   for (let col of collections.filter(x => x.match(/^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}\./))) {
      print(`db.getSiblingDB('${doc._id}').getCollection('${col}').drop()`);
   }
})
```

Then execute the printed commands. But be careful, some of these temporary collections might be currently used. I suggest to stop the application, then all temp collections will be released. And the balancer should be stopped.

You may also try the [cleanupOrphaned](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/command/cleanupOrphaned/) command.

Note, the name pattern for temporary collection depends on MongoDB version. For example on version 6.0 the name is like `tmp.agg_out.620aa2ca-4a35-45ec-829e-2e7ca3d823bc`

You may investigate why these temp collections are not dropped automatically. Have a look at the application code. Typically collection `9a79fb83-7c4e-4927-88ec-b462438b8471.galileo.prepared_data` would be created by aggregation pipelines like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   ...
   { $out: 'galileo.prepared_data' }
])
```

Comment: What I ended up doing is a create a script to dump/drop/restore. After about 15 of those, I finally managed to set FCV to 5.0.

Comment: I will enquire with dev about these DBs, if they are indeed temp. They were created long time ago. It would be great if I could drop them all, there are several thousands of them.